# Redux common state/Error handling in reducers

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I am working on a WebSocket application that uses React/Redux stack with Sage as the side-effects handler. Saga dispatches events on incoming WebSocket messages and specific slice reducers either
1. Handle the message and update the state
2. Reply to Websocket message immediately - based on the current state
3. Raise an error - Invalid message

I would like to contain the business logic in reducers, hence would like the reducers to raise WebSocket send events or set an error state, rather than splitting these 2 to Saga handler. Strategy  I am looking at is to have global states state.outgoingMessages and state.errors where any slice reducer can set these states.  If an outgoingMessage is set the sage middleware would on resumption would write back to the WebSocket, if an error state is set an Error Component would render this.

I don't think I am violating any reducer/saga rules, however I have the dilemma of passing down a common state to reducers. There being quite a bit of discussion around this topic
https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/BeyondCombineReducers.html#sharing-data-between-slice-reducers

provides a recipe of passing down additional sate. I can have a higher order reducer and pass down additional states outgoingMessages and error to slice reducers, would this be an anit-pattern, or is there a better way to handle the problem altogether?

Comment: Can you share a bit of what `slices` you have? I don't see why you cannot have a `communications` slice that handles this and triggers a saga to handle any follow up side effect. I would definitely not put heavy business logic in a reducer function as they are meant to be pure functions that mutate the redux store state.

Comment: Slices have a hierarchical relationship, like orders and items, The messages are for these slices specifically. How would a communications slice work?Where would you put the business logic? in sagas? https://redux.js.org/docs/faq/CodeStructure.html#how-should-i-split-my-logic-between-reducers-and-action-creators-where-should-my-business-logic-go

Comment: The communication slice would have state related to communication such as error, outgoingMessages, etc. When you need to pass data specific to any other slice, you can simply fire an slice specific action from the communication Saga. You can even hooked another Saga with the slice specific action if you need an asynchronous operation for the slice.

Comment: That means I have to do business logic in sagas, I would really like to keep saga as a side-effect handler, and have reducers(pure functions) handle the state based on incoming data

Comment: Not necessarily. You can have separate modules/classes that handle business logic. You just have to keep extending the Single Responsibility Principle. For instance, if you have some sort of MessageQueue, you should have a component that handles all the business logic of your MessageQueue. The saga just passes some input and waits for the output. Once that's done, the saga just fire an action based on the output. Neither a saga nor a reducer should have heavy business logic.